# GoogleCertificateRslt: not allowed + com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier library

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

Does anybody have any experience with these issues and/or know of the consent verifier library? I'm struggling to find literally any sort of documentation regarding it online and it's currently causing errors within my project.

Here's the exact warnings I'm pulling:

```
  Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/MapsDynamite.dm': No such file or directory
    
    Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.maybefinalgeoguessr, may result in stale flags.
                                                                                                        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.maybefinalgeoguessr, sha256=[....], atk=false, ver=230714044.true (go/gsrlt)
                                                                                                            at ajk.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):3)
                                                                                                            at ajk.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                            at aku.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                            at yn.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):1)
                                                                                                            at yp.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):0)
                                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
                                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
                                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.maybefinalgeoguessr, sha256=[.....], atk=false, ver=230714044.true (go/gsrlt)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
                                                                                                            at fd.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                            at rs.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):4)
                                                                                                            at jj.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                            at ki.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                            at ki.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):3)
                                                                                                            at ki.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):2)
                                                                                                            at km.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230714044@23.07.14 (190400-0):69)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

and here is my minimal reproducible sample:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.maybefinalgeoguessr;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanorama;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {

    private StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama;
    private boolean secondlocation = false;
    private static final double MIN_LATITUDE = -90;
    private static final double MAX_LATITUDE = 90;
    private static final double MIN_LONGITUDE = -180;
    private static final double MAX_LONGITUDE = 180;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment = (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemapstreetview);
        streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);



    }


    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {

        Random random = new Random();
        double lat = MIN_LATITUDE + (MAX_LATITUDE - MIN_LATITUDE) * random.nextDouble();
        double lng = MIN_LONGITUDE + (MAX_LONGITUDE - MIN_LONGITUDE) * random.nextDouble();
        //LatLng randomLocation = new LatLng(lat,lng);
        LatLng debug = new LatLng(40.3356, 75.9269);

        this.streetViewPanorama = streetViewPanorama;
        this.streetViewPanorama.setPosition(debug);


    }
}
```

Manifest XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Maybefinalgeoguessr"
        tools:targetApi="33">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name= "com.google.android.streetview.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/geocoding_api_key" />

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Maybefinalgeoguessr">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/googlemapstreetview"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

plug ins:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and also please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question and that the community could help you better. With that said, I would like to ask if does this affect loading your map in any way?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75915360/18422887) out as this could be related to what you're going through.

Comment: @Yrll I have since updated my post with a minimal reproducible example. The issue is actually unrelated to maps but rather my Street View API. However, yes, the use does make my app incapable of loading my Street View image. A black image appears where the image does.