# Google Maps in Flutter is crashing the App

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

In my flutter app I have used "google_maps_flutter" package to display map by passing latitude and longitude. Earlier it was working fine but from few days when I open the google map module in the app, the app is crashing down with the following error.

"**Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed**"[image]

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737816/googlecertificatesrslt-not-allowed-in-kotlin-android-application/75915360#75915360

Comment: @Yrll I have gone throw the above URL which you have mentioned but I didn't got any solution to it

Comment: Yes, it has no solution, because the error you mentioned is just a harmless, yet annoying warning message. It does not cause or show any problems on Maps SDK functionality. So I don't think this is the one that's causing your crash. With that said, please check if there are additional errors on the log and share it here. As the issue could have rooted elsewhere.